# Fizzbuzz program in C

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

Okay, this really isn't as much a fizzbuzz question as it is a C question.

I wrote some simple code in C for printing out fizzbuzz as is required.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 30;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", (i % 15) == 0 ? "fizzbuzz" : (i % 5) == 0 ? "buzz" : (i % 3) == 0 ? "fizz" : i);
}
```

Now, the last else statement obviously doesn't work since printf is accepting a string whereas 'i' is an int. 
My question is, is there any sort of cast that I can apply to convert the 'i' into a string?

EDIT: I should mention, what I'm really asking is if this fizzbuzz test can be done using a single print statement. No particular reason why I want it to be a single print statement only other than curiosity of as to whether it can be done.

EDIT2: Question answered and here's my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, n=30;        
    for (i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        printf((!(i%3) || !(i%5)) ? "%s\n" : "%d\n", !(i % 15) ? "fizzbuzz" : !(i % 5) ? "buzz" : !(i % 3) ? "fizz" : i);
}
```

http://codepad.org/DN7yBW99

Comment: Why not just use `%d`?

Comment: How would I print the strings then?

Comment: Seperate the `printf`s and use `if`s. Its easier that way and also reduces confusion.

Comment: you could look at `itoa`

Comment: Triple ternary operator = interview fail.

Comment: Who said anything about an interview?

Comment: Sounds more like http://codegolf.stackexchange.com to me ...

Comment: ^Didn't know something like that existed. Sorry :(

Comment: The ternary operator fails: the type of the operands and not consistent. `i` is converted to `char*` and passed as such, `printf` expects an `int` for the `%d` conversion. Undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've cornered yourself by the way you've tried to put all the logic inside of the `printf` call. It would be better to write it out the "slow" way first, then look for ways to optimize it afterward.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0)
        printf("fizzbuzz\n");
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
        printf("buzz\n");
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
        printf("fizz\n");
    else
        printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

#### Addendum: Do it with just one printf...

```
/* The following code is NOT recommended... */

int isFizz     = (i % 3 == 0      ) ? 1 : 0;
int isBuzz     = (i % 5 == 0      ) ? 1 : 0;
int isFizzBuzz = (isFizz && isBuzz) ? 1 : 0;

printf(
    (isFizz || isBuzz) ? "%s\n" : "%d\n",
    (
        isFizzBuzz ? "fizzbuzz" :
        isFizz     ? "fizz"     :
        isBuzz     ? "buzz"     :
        i
    )
);
```

http://codepad.org/LMr5WdIm

Comment: The thing I forgot to mention is that the whole point of asking the question was to find a way to use just **one** print statement for doing the whole thing. I am not new to CS, just new to the C language. I can very well do the fizzbuzz test, the way you mentioned. I can also do it quite easily using **two** print statements. The question is whether it can be done using just one.

Comment: I should also mention, there is no deep reason why I'd want to do it using one print statement only, just my curiosity!

Comment: @SilverSlash Updated with one possible solution (which I don't recommend, but hey, we're just in the business of experimentation at this stage anyway)

Comment: Great! I did think of this but I was just hoping there would be some cast operator than can do the conversion easily. But thanks!

Comment: Your solution with a single printf does not work: the second parameter is not passed as `int`. Undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the args to printf by passing the string literals *as the format string*, rather than using a `%s` to print them.  This takes advantage of the fact that you know there are no `%` characters in `"fizz"` or `"buzz"`.  [It's guaranteed to be safe to pass unused args to printf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579752/224132).

To make the source readable, pull the logic to select a format string out of the `printf()` itself, and store it in a local variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n=30;        
    for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
        int fizzy = (i % 3 == 0);
        int buzzy = (i % 5 == 0);

        const char *fmt = (fizzy && buzzy) ? "fizzbuzz\n" :
                          fizzy            ? "fizz\n"     :
                          buzzy            ? "buzz\n"     :
                          "%d\n";
        printf(fmt, i);
    }
}
```

It can be good style, and possibly make better asm, to conditionally determine the args you're going to pass and then make one call, instead of writing out the same function call with different args.  This can be good if most of the args you're going to pass are the same in different branches, which is not the case here.

Normally it's better to just use `puts` (implicit `\n` appended) or `fputs` to print constant strings that don't need formatting.  Compilers know this, and [even optimize `printf("Hello World!\n");` or `printf("%s\n", "Hello World!")` to `puts("Hello World!");`](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-xc++-std%3Dc11+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOID2A6ACwD4AoE8DJAWwENwAKANxxDgEoSBvEpXpCpGAC8AZgAMAbj7SkPPgDMcAJyT0BIJEKQBGKSBRCwegNTG2SbjL4D5IAF52AnptUaApEhGatYthLlWAgBGMA7OWmpIHgCs3ki%2B/gEyEDhgmEgQBDQqAFTyVJQRtmFIAGSlSCFh5gD8SABExXZVdgA6YPVIAFxJVn39SE3OA7x1jfZtHTI9I7MyLcMjYy3tndIzc5v1bnCr/v0ADkoU8vT5GAA0/H5JAL4k9ySg8vEkzKxIBAhQUDjaTCx2BYkEcTvRtmhVld6gAJb6/JAAdWUUDgAEJ6n4kPd3nBPvCcAAmAGscycEHHMAYU6wglIlHo1ZY%2B4AehZlRwGAISGyyBwBwwICo9gQeIwOCQGDoUAAtBAaD80EgcC8DjAMGg3oDlQKhSK4AB9cVGgggNAkoHktUa8Fwn4S5FKVEY5lkEhswScnWC4V2UVaj5fe0iC1kilg2n2qKQjrQx3OzFSHHaoO/AAsoeBoKpNLtvzcaHq0PpTsZHVdwAQYGw8iAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) in trivial cases.  This trick means that even the fixed-string prints still make a call to the more expensive `printf`.  (Besides readability, this is one of the concrete reasons why it's not a great choice in this particular instance.)

gcc and [clang compile this into asm that works the way the source does](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-xc++-std%3Dc11+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOID2A6ACwD4AoE8DJAWwENwAKANxxDgEoSBvEpXpCpGAC8AZgAMAbj7SkPPgDMcAJyT0BIJEKQBGKSBRCwegNTG2SbjL4D5IAF52AnptUaApEhGatYthLlWAgBGMA7OWmpIHgCs3ki%2B/gEyEDhgmEgQBDQqAFTyVJQRtmFIAGSlSCFh5gD8SABExXZVdgA6YPVIAFxJVn39SE3OA7x1jfZtHTI9I7MyLcMjYy3tndIzc5v1bnCr/v0ADkoU8vT5GAA0/H5JAL4k9ySg8vEkzKxIBAhQUDjaTCx2BYkEcTvRtmhVld6gAJb6/JAAdWUUDgAEJ6n4kPd3nBPvCcAAmAGscycEHHMAYU6wglIlHo1ZY%2B4AehZlRwGAISGyyBwBwwICo9gQeIwOCQGDoUAAtBAaD80EgcC8DjAMGg3oDlQKhSK4AB9cVGgggNAkoHktUa8Fwn4S5FKVEY5lkEhswScnWC4V2UVaj5fe0iC1kilg2n2qKQjrQx3OzFSHHaoO/AAsoeBoKpNLtvzcaHq0PpTsZHVdwAQYGw8iAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3): `printf` always gets two args (in the `rdi` and `rsi` registers), but sometimes the format string doesn't use the 2nd arg.  Change `-O3` to `-Os` to make gcc use `div` instead of a multiplicative inverse.

They don't unroll the loop to match the modulo pattern, or strength-reduce the modulos to down-counters, or anything clever [like you'd do in a hand-written asm FizzBuzz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334034/fizzbuzz-in-assembly-segmentation-fault/37494090#37494090).

For a devious way to write a compact FizzBuzz, see [CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58635/30206), where a `%s%s%.d` format string conditionally gets empty strings.  The `%.d` is specifies a precision of 0.  Non-zero integers print normally, but `0` prints as the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Sorry... i just realized that this thread was for a C solution

Recursive implementation:

```
vector<string> FizzBuzz::execute(int n) {

    if(n == 0)
        return vector<string>();

    auto push = n % 15 == 0 ? "fizzbuzz" :
                n % 3 == 0 ? "fizz" :
                n % 5 == 0 ? "buzz" :
                to_string(n);

    auto execution = execute(n-1);
    execution.push_back(push);
    return execution;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as suggested you could use `itoa();`. Sample code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
int num=23;
char snum[3];
itoa(num,snum,10);
printf("%s",snum);
}
```

itoa is used to convert an `int` to a `string`, the parameters are as follows.

```
itoa(int num, char string [], int base);
```

The first parameter is the number you are converting. The second parameter is the string/`char` array you want to store the converted strong into. Lastly, the third parameter is the base the number to be converted is in.

Comment: `itoa` is **not** a standard C function, and it's unnecessary for this program, where you can use the standard `%s` format of `printf`.

Answer (score -2):

```
int n;
printf("input: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) 
        printf("FizzBuzz\n");
    else if(i % 3 == 0) 
        printf("Fizz\n");
    else if(i % 5 == 0)
        printf("Buzz\n");
    else 
        printf("%d\n", i);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Why reposting a previous answer?